# Is it possible to disable anti-aliasing on vector images?

Tags: android, wear-os

On Wear OS in ambient mode, only black or white pixels should be displayed (no grays). Anti-aliasing a black and white image introduces gray pixels. Now, anti-alising can be disabled for a TextView by writing `textView.paint.isAntiAlias = false` (in Kotlin) but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for vector images. The one thing I've tried is adding `android:antialias="false"` to the image XML file, but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Note that most newer Wear OS devices support up to a limited color palette in ambient mode (as well as greyscale). What made you think you could only use black or white?

Comment: Not that you _can't_, certainly, but black and white are the most energy efficient colors to display, according to Google. Grays are especially discouraged.

Comment: Do you have a reference to where 'grays are especially discouraged'? The docs [actually say](https://designguidelines.withgoogle.com/wearos/patterns/always-on.html#always-on-style): "Use a limited color palette" and "Aim to have 95% of its pixels black".

Comment: [This doc](https://designguidelines.withgoogle.com/wearos/style/color.html) says: "Grays should be avoided, as any tint of color is more battery-efficient than any shade of gray or white."

Comment: that relates to backgrounds, not aliasing in text / icons.

Comment: No, nowhere does it imply that it's only for backgrounds. Furthermore, [this](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on) doc implies that anti-aliasing should be turned off for text, which correlates to the recommendation to avoid grays..

Comment: try with `setFilterBitmap(false);`

Comment: Calling setFilterBitmap(false) on the image seems to have no effect. https://i.imgur.com/DNqn582.png

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do it in XML.

Personally I've only done this when drawing straight to a canvas. Setting `setAntiAlias(false)` (don't remember if we ended up using `setDither(false)` and `setFilterBitmap(false)` too) on the `Paint` did the trick.

You can try using a [`DrawableWrapper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/graphics/drawable/DrawableWrapper) and make the necessary changes in the `draw()` method. Unfortunately this means that you have to set all your drawables in code, but at least you'll still be able to rely on an `ImageView`.